# Strip trailing spaces from factor labels using dplyr chain

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe loaded that has trailing white spaces in the factor labels. I am trying to remove those trailing spaces in every factor in the dataframe but am unsuccessful so far.

Reproducable example

```
lvls <- c('a   ',
          'b   ',
          'c   ')
set.seed(314)
raw <- data.frame(a = factor(sample(lvls,100, replace=T)),
                  b = sample(1:100,100))

proc <- raw %>% mutate_each(funs(ifelse(is.factor(.),
                                        factor(as.character(trimws(.)),
                                               labels=unique(as.character(.))),
                                        .))) 

str(proc)
```

gives

```
'data.frame':   100 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ a: int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ b: int  31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 31 ...
```

Which is wrong on two levels. The factor has no labels. Only the first observation is repeated 100 times

Comment: we can do this even without `dplyr` if you want. You just want to `trimws()` on any factor variable if present right?

Comment: I know but I now want to know what I am doing wrong with `dplyr`

Comment: Check `strip.white` in `read.table`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`mutate_if` is your friend. If you don't care if you convert to character, you can just use

```
raw %>% mutate_if(is.factor, trimws)
```

which suggests that you can just reconvert to factor:

```
raw %>% mutate_if(is.factor, funs(factor(trimws(.))))
```

If you want to maintain the type, you can use the more convoluted

```
raw %>% mutate_if(is.factor, funs(`levels<-`(., trimws(levels(.)))))
```

---

The base R equivalent would be

```
raw[] <- lapply(raw, function(x){if (is.factor(x)) {levels(x) <- trimws(levels(x))} ; x})
```

though if it's a single variable and you know which, base is pretty clean:

```
levels(raw$a) <- trimws(levels(raw$a))
```

---

Edit: Now `forcats::relabel` (part of the tidyverse) makes changing levels with a function easier:

```
raw %>% mutate_if(is.factor, fct_relabel, trimws)
```

or for a single variable,

```
raw %>% mutate(a = fct_relabel(a, trimws))
```

It will accept anonymous functions as well, including purrr-style `~trimws(.x)` if you like.

Answer (score 1):

something along these lines?

```
l = lapply(raw, function(x) {if(is.factor(x)){x <- trimws(x)};x})
head(as.data.frame(l))
#  a  b
#1 a 31
#2 a 55
#3 c 68
#4 a 18
#5 a 72
#6 a 64
```

Comment: You can also try `raw[] <- lapply(raw, function(x) type.convert(trimws(as.character(x)), as.is = TRUE))`  Great post without using any external packages. Plus one.